# Ablation of pyrolitic graphite utilizing electrochemical means

Tags: electrochemistry, carbon-allotropes

I am looking for a process to ablate the surface of a pyrolytic graphite (PG) sample.

I am thinking that an electrochemical process might be the answer; however, since this is not my field, I am looking for input from the experts on this forum.

I propose utilizing an electrolytic cell containing a strong acid electrolyte (ie. H2SO4) and a platinum electrode. The PG sample acts as the cathode and the Pt electrode is the anode. A 10V DC source is applied to the system in order to enable the ablation process.

I chose this method since it is an approach used to exfoliate graphite.

It is optimal for the process to be expedient, of which, this is not. So, any alterations to this method or alternate methods to expedite the process would be helpful.

Comment: What is the meaning of "to ablate the surface" ?

Comment: To create surface roughness by eroding the top layer(s) of graphite in the PG stack. For example, to create multiple indentations on the surface.

Comment: Don't you think putting the graphite at the anode would not be a solution of the problem ?

Comment: I do see that a paper I referenced <https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja5017156#> does designate the graphite as the anode and the Pt electrode as the cathode. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Assuming that this is a viable solution to the problem, the question still remains - Is their an alternate solution that would expedite the processes of erosion?

Comment: The corrosion is much faster if the surface be corroded is at the anode.